# Вопрос по потокам в C++ (fstream)

Tags: c++, файлы, fstream

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const char* path = "test.txt";
    char tmp;
    fstream fs(path, ios::in | ios::out);

    if (!fs)
        cout << "Err";
    else
    {
        while (fs >> tmp)
        {
            if (tmp == '!' || tmp == '?')
            {
                fs.seekg(-1, fs.cur);
                fs << '.';
                fs.seekg(1);
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Собственно сам вопрос,была задача поменять ! и ? на точки,а спорный момент появился на строчке `fs.seekg(1);`
Препод сказал,что это лишнее,да и по смыслу тоже.Эта команда двигает маркер на 1 вправо(?),но без него у меня текст в файле зацикливается до бесконечности, пример 
Есть файл с текстом qwe!!!,с этой строчкой нормально все,вывод -> qwe... ,а без нее вывод-> qwe.we.we.we.we.we.we.we.we.we.we.we.we.we.we.we. и дальше так,как это работает или у меня настройки какие стоят в визуалке,что это так работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
fs << '.';
```

напишите

```
fs << '.' << flush;
```

чтоб он у вас понимал, что файл изменился, и сбрасывал буфер. Тогда ваш `fs.seekg(1);` не нужен.

Еще - по-хорошему, следовало бы добавить после открытия

```
fs.unsetf(fs.skipws);
```

чтоб читать и пробелы тоже...

Comment: а зачем читать пробелы?

Comment: Хотя бы потому что завтра может потребоваться заменять пробелы на подчерки. Или еще что-то. Я не уверен - точнее, по опыту ruSO, почти уверен в том, что если бы стояло требование заменять пробелы, то этот вопрос встал бы здесь - почему не читаются пробелы...